# Tuples in type members using F#

Tags: f#, types, tuples, member

I have a simple question. Why does this not work?

```
type Test1() =
  member o.toTuple = 1.,2.,3.

type Test2() =
  member o.test (x: float, y: float, z: float) = printfn "test"
  member o.test (x: Test1) = o.test x.toTuple
```

The error is:

> Type constraint mismatch. The type      float * float * float     is not compatible with type     Test1     The type 'float * float * float' is not compatible with the type 'Test1'

and

> The type 'float * float * float' is not compatible with the type 'Test1'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't work because the first member test is considered as a multiple argument method in case of overloading.
If you need a tupled one, you have to add extra parentheses:

```
type Test2() =
    member o.test ((x: float, y: float, z: float)) = printfn "test"
    member o.test (x: Test1) = o.test x.toTuple
```

See explanation of Don Syme [here](http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/4042.aspx).

Note that if you don't want to add extra parens, you still can deconstruct the tuple and use the multiple argument call:

```
type Test2() =
    member o.test (x: float, y: float, z: float) = printfn "test"
    member o.test (x: Test1) = let a,b,c = x.toTuple in o.test(a,b,c)
```

Answer (score 4):

Rename your first method in `Type2` to something other than `test`. You second method is shadowing your first, and thus confusing the compiler.

```
type Test1() =
   member o.toTuple = 1.,2.,3.

type Test2() =
  member o.print (x: float, y: float, z: float) = printfn "test"
  member o.test (x: Test1) = o.print x.toTuple
```